# Paradox of weight increasing with relative velocity

Tags: gravity, mass, relativity

I am traveling past earth near the speed of light, I see an 80kg (rest mass) man standing on a scale and it reads 80 kg. However, due to special relativity I see the mass of the earth and the man are both doubled and hence the gravitational force between them should be 4 times and the scale should read 320kg. The reading on the scale display can't be both 80kg and 320kg.

What is the explanation?

I did search both the web and stack exchange and could not find an answer. I saw the "duplicate post" before posting and it refers to a moving mass on a stationary surface whereas this case is 2 masses that are stationary relative to each other and a observer moving relative to both, I see this as a different case and look forward to any solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does relativistic mass have weight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63961/)

Comment: The answer to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/157014) might be helpful.